# ASP.NET MVC 3 and One-To-Many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, one-to-many

This is a question about Models, ASP.NET MVC 3 and relationships. I'm using the code-first approach.

Imagine this simple typical scenario of an User with its Blog Posts:

```
public class User
{
   public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
   public virtual string Nickname { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
   public virtual int PostId { get; set; }
   public virtual string BlogText { get; set; }
}
```

I made it very very simple.

Well. When I create a controller using the *Controller with Read/Write actions and views using Entity Framework*, the collection of Posts is not considered. It's being ignored. So, I can't get this relationship to work.

If, in place of the collection, there was a single object (*public virtual string Email*, for example) it works normally.

I'm asking myself and to you:

- Why
- How do I put references to collections in my model?

It should be a simple task, I really can't understand why it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

POCO should look like below to have one-to-many relationship:

```
public class Post
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string BlogText { get; set; }

   public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nickname { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, really, try to generate the controller (Right Click on the Controllers folder => Add Controller => Scaffolding Options: 'Controller with read/write actions...' => Model Class: User => Data context class: new data context). It doesn't work. It only creates context methods for User. Posts is not present.

Comment: You might want to create a separate controller for `Post` like `PostController`, because that is a different entity.

Comment: If I create a different controller I will not have the automatic scaffolding features of the Entity Framework, I think.

Comment: Yeah, it clearly works as if the models were separated. But I want to tie them each other. I need a single Data Context that makes me able to call, for example: Users.Posts.All()

Comment: When you creating a new `PostController`, don't select `<New Data Context>`, instead select the previously created data context.

Comment: Ok, but it still doesn't allow me to make User.Posts.All(), because the previously created scaffold remains unchanged!